# What is reliable, autoconnecting wifi manager?

Tags: opensuse, wifi, networkmanager

openSUSE 11.4, one wifi connection with static IP.

Requirements:

1. after autologin connection should be automatically established with defined static IP
2. after connection dropped, manager should try to connect again and again and it should never give up

I use KNetworkManager, but despite I posted reports about both issues, to this very day it lacks such basic features.

Is there any wifi manager which handles both cases correctly? Or are there some workarounds to make KNM work correctly (1 -- KNM auto-connects with **dynamic** IP initially ignoring the settings, 2 -- it does not try to reconnect at all).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net) is a very good Wi-Fi manager. It uses the traditional tools for network management without extra layers. It meets your requirements.

Remember to stop and uninstall all NetworkManager packages for avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. First try out didn't work out (openSUSE package is not too well built and conflicts with KNM), but I will try it again. Looks promising anyway.

Comment: You're welcome :) . I'm using the unofficial KDE frontend in Debian http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=132366 .

Comment: I've used wicd before and it's the best wifi manager for Linux I've found.

Comment: Wicd is fantastic. I'm a fan of curses-based client.

Answer (score 3):

It must be just the KDE front-end because the basic NetworkManager meets both of the requirements above for me and has for all versions over the last several years.

Is it possible for you to either use the NetworkManager provided interface instead of the KDE wrapper or that you are using the wrapper wrong and have it mis-configured so that it doesn't work? Particularly the bit about it ignoring your settings on startup sounds like you maybe setting something in the wrong place. Do you have network scripts that perhaps conflict with NM?

Comment: The settings are pretty straightforward and it is hard to make mistake (I don't even know how). I don't use any scripts. When you wrote about NM interface, did you mean writing my own scripts to manage NM directly? It would be close to writing manager on my own :-)